# Is there evidence that the use of dependency injection improves outcomes in software engineering?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-containers, evidence-based

Notwithstanding its popularity, is there any empirical evidence that shows that Dependency Injection (and/or using a DI container) helps with, say, reducing bug counts, improving maintainability, or increasing development velocity on real-life software projects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency injection: How to sell it](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/149792/dependency-injection-how-to-sell-it)  And before you look only on the headline and think "hey, this is not literally a dupe" - read that other question and the answers, I think they fit very well to this question here.

Comment: @DocBrown That question doesn't have an empirical answers, and it is also about "selling" DI in a work-related environment. It was closed because of that. I don't have any particular opinion either way This question is about evidence. I'll reword the details.

Comment: I've reworded the details to make them more abstract. This question is not asking for opinions, intuitions and hand-waving but asking for evidence (of the scientific sort) about the efficacy of DI. Even if no one answers it, the lack of answers has value in itself. Furthermore the question marked as a possible duplicate has been closed, so even if there was empirical evidence it wouldn't be answerable there.

Comment: Accept the fact that lots of practices of professional software development don't have "scientific evidence", they are based on practical experience. So even if you now have worsened your question just for trying to make it artifically "less duplicate" than the one I linked to, the real question you should have asked for getting the answers you really want to know is that other question I linked to. And by the way, now it seems you are asking for third-party resources, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: My experience got me looking for evidence, but it was tangential to the primary thrust of the question. There was no artifice in its asking. As for asking for third-party resources, that seems to a somewhat contrived reading of the question. Furthermore, the benefits in the "selling DI" question don't address the outcomes I asked for.

Comment: Very few techniques in software development are accompanied by scientific proof, of the kind where you can point to a research paper and declare definitively that a technique is valuable.  Consequently, most of us rely on experience and cost/benefit analyses to justify our decisions.  You choose a technique like dependency injection because you need the benefits it provides, and because those benefits outweigh the costs.  Admittedly, that calculus is always somewhat subjective.

Comment: Empirical evidence  "of the scientific sort" - how could there be one if not in a research paper or similar sources on that topic? So there is IMHO nothing contrived in reading your question that way. What you are really after is arguments to discuss with a project team or that technical lead you originally mentioned (edited out or not). That other question I linked to gives you exactly that, I hoped to help you with this. Sorry if you don't see any value in this for your case.

Comment: One of the pillars of Scrum is "empiricism". I doubt that Scrum teams publish scientific papers after every retro. Personal experience counts as evidence as well "we had an x LOC .NET system and had a bug rate of y bugs per week. We introduced Unity for DI, as part of a unit testing effort and bought the bug rate down to z".  As for the tech lead, I left the project months ago.

Comment: @DocBrown Honestly, I see this neither as a duplicate, nor as being off-topic, myself. The rationale and efficacy of a development practice seems *very* relevant to SE.SE. And, I'm going to provide an answer. The OP probably won't *like* my answer ... but, I think it's worth having an **objective** answer (almost-answer) to whether TPOs and PMs can expect to see their teams productivity magically go up (or their bug rates drop) as soon as someone shouts "dependency injection."

Comment: The problem I see with answering this well is that so much of what people call DI is dripping with frameworks. Depending on how their used these range from helpful to nightmarish. We used to just call DI reference passing. Someone could probably find data about OOP code that uses reference passing being easier to maintain than procedural code. But that might not have the focus you'd like.

Comment: @CandiedOrange No. The right answer is, "if there is data, it doesn't apply to you anyway." But, if you give me a few minutes, I'll have that basically typed up for you to see!

Comment: "lots of practices of professional software development don't have "scientific evidence", they are based on practical experience." This is a sign that software development is barely understood and not something we should be complacent about. "does there exist evidence for X" is a question we should always be asking, even if we're not trying to sell something.

Comment: @svidgen: your answer is a good one, and I see you agree to me that the OP asked literally the wrong question (and it seems you already got downvotes from people who obviously did not understand the latter). My vote for closing **as a dupe** (and not as off-topic, was you wrote) was  for his [original question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/362886/1). Then he started to edit it in a shape where it looks like a third party request, and that really degraded the quality of the question.

Comment: agree with @DocBrown, edit made the question worse. See [Is empirical evidence off topic here?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7572/31260) and [Is a question about research material on-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5589/31260)

Comment: @gnat it's probably worth starting a distinct meta question for "evidence" questions, which were added to the scope of that "off site resource" meta answer long after I upvoted it. Sure, asking us to go find stats is probably not helpful. But, the essence of the question is perfectly reasonable. And, to me, it sounds like laziness to so quickly call it off topic. The comments here specifically give the impression that we're a bunch of DI dogmatists that simply *can't* defend our practices. Well, we can. And we should.

Answer (score 14):

### TLDR

The empirical data is irrelevant. Tools and practices (like DI) solve *particular* problems. Understand your problems, learn how to use the tools, and it'll become obvious when a tool is valuable -- *and* you'll be able to explain the outcomes much more prophetically than any generalized, aggregated, empirical data.

---

And now, with much more verbosity ...

#### Is there empirical evidence?

Sure, probably. Or at least maybe. But, who cares? **It isn't relevant.**

A statistical cost-benefit analysis of DI may be interesting academically, but, it doesn't necessarily predict individual success. Aggregated results hide individual successes *and failures.* And, I might argue that data regarding "evangelical" practices is particularly poisonous. These disciplines tend to attract both zealots and fools, both of which obscure the net impact of a "pure" implementation, and *either* of which you could *be!*

#### So, how do we know Dependency Injection is valuable *at all?*

Good question! GREAT question, in fact. And I'm with you -- I hate wasting time and mental effort on dogmatic "best practices" that no one can justify. So, I'm glad you asked.

Uhh. But, here's the embarrassing problem ... In *general* terms, **you *don't* know.** And, even more embarrassingly, your code may not actually get better in any way by introducing DI.

---

***GASP!***

```
    ⊙▃⊙     . . .      (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
```

...

---

So, maybe now you're wondering ...

### Why should I bother 'bout things ain't been proved er nuthin'!?

First of all, let's all just -- on everywhich side of the debate -- just settle down. I can assure you that between the dogmatism and skepticism lies a beautiful paradise of reason and level-headedness. (And the occasional eccentric SE.SE post.) And, the POAP can lead you there.

... By which I mean, [the Principle of Applying Principles](http://www.fragiledeveloper.com/2017/05/the-principle-of-applying-principles.html):

> Principles, patterns, and practices are not final purposes. The good and proper application of each is therefore inspired **and constrained** by a superior, more final purpose.
>
> **You need to understand why you're doing what you're doing!**
>
> (The POAP is not exempt from the POAP.)

<sup>(I'd say, "emphasis mine," but it's from my own "blog" anyway. So, it's *all* mine!)</sup>

Let me reiterate the main point there: **You need to understand why you're doing what you're doing.**

And perhaps to clarify, it doesn't usually make sense to take any given "something" (like Dependency Injection), and use it without already understanding what problem it solves -- **for you specifically.** If you understand your problems and how the "something" (like DI) works, it'll be somewhat "obvious" how helpful the "something" is, very much regardless of what the generalized, aggregated, empirical data suggests.

If DI's helpfulness or *un*-helpfulness to you is not obvious -- or at least beyond your reasoning powers -- you either don't understand DI, or you don't understand your own problems.

---

Let's consider a real-world "parable."

We need to construct a box. We have wood. We have nails. And, we have two tools: [A standard claw hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claw_hammer) and [a screwdriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screwdriver).

Now, we may have some broad empirical data to show that boxes constructed with screwdrivers are significantly more robust boxes overall, as compared to those constructed with hammers. But, if you try to screw those nails in, you won't end up with a box at all. And, if you try to smack them in with the screwdriver, you might eventually get them in; but, it'll require significantly more time and effort, and the final result will be less precise (and robust) than had you simply used the hammer.

And, if you've ever seen someone use either tool before, and if you understand what a box looks like, the decision is obvious.

**Telekinesis!**

Err ... hmm...

---

#### Yeah-So, what problem does Dependency Injection solve?

It works to prevents rigid, un-configurable code, which is often therefore un-*testable*.

It does this by permitting *invoking* code to decide what objects a module operates with. And I know you're thinking it, and you're right: This isn't even a remotely new concept. Method/Function parameters have existed since algebra happened.

We started evangelizing basic parameter passing, calling it "Dependency Injection", once we accumulated and inherited enough code to see our imbalances. The mountains of code we were sitting on top of couldn't easily be changed, tested, or even *reused*, simply because the dependencies were hidden away.

Hence, the zealous crusade for Dependency Injection...

#### K. But, I can pass arguments in just fine. Why the *frameworks*?

As I understand it, DI *frameworks* primarily solve the problem of boilerplate buildup (due to overzealous DI, IMO) -- particularly when there are standard "default" dependencies for all modules that require them. DI frameworks do magical (potentially even naughty!) things to slip those default dependencies in when they're not explicitly passed at the point of invocation. (Same effect as a [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) when used in this manner, mind you!)

Dependency Injection, as a "discipline", is actually really hard to get right. It's not a matter of using DI or not; it's a matter of knowing which dependencies are likely to change or need mocking and injecting *those*. And then, it's matter of deciding whether DI fits the better than some alternative, like Service Location ...

But, I'd encourage you to [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+problem+does+dependency+injection+solve&rlz=1C1MSIM_enUS711US711&oq=what+problem+does+dependency&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.5144j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), maybe see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection), possibly talk to a super-experienced and successful developer in your industry, and post specific examples to [CR.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you been sniffing some of @CandiedOrange's glue? +1 for the Principle of Applied Purposes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wish I could say I new which glue we were talking about! I've had a longstanding vendetta against faith-based engineering... Unless you're referring to the narrative -- possibly even zany -- nature of the post?

Comment: Side note to the downvoters, nothing fills me more with confidence in my decision to answer a question than well-balanced up and down votes! ... It *would* be nice to see your criticisms in the comments though ...

Comment: @RobertHarvey not sure which of my many glues you're referring to but I find myself agreeing to every word of this. It's easy to think a hammer sucks when you use it on screws.

Comment: Started editing to include more detail about DI specifically and bubble the TLDR to the top. And then the kids started fussing, so I hit Save. ... If I inadvertently lost the essence of what you upvoted (for those of you that did), please let me know!

Comment: "Sure, probably. Or at least maybe. But, who cares? It isn't relevant." Strong disagree. If, as a purely hypothetical example, we found a couple dozen papers all saying it makes things **worse**, that'd be pretty relevant! It's alright to say "the research we have is probably irrelevant", but we still should be seeking it out.

Comment: @Hovercouch I took that to mean "It's not relevant until you understand the problem you're trying to solve", because until you do it's difficult to see if those couple dozen papers actually apply to your problem.  Back to the hammer analogy, all the papers you found could have been written by folks who had screws and a screwdriver and we're naysaying the value of hammers.

Answer (score 12):

I searched Google, Google Scholar, ACM, and IEEE Here were the papers I've been able to find:

- [Dependency Injection frameworks: an improvement to testability?](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2:852739). It argues that "testability" can be defined as "low cohesion". It states that DI leads to lower cohesion, lower cohesion is correlated with higher test coverage, and that higher test coverage is correlated with more faults found. It says that, based on this, DI improves testability.

  I don't like this for a couple of reasons. First of all, it's saying "A is correlated with B, B is correlated with C, so A causes C", which is a couple of steps in the logic I don't see as being well supported by the paper. Second, it admits that it's only measuring "subparts of testability", and that 'testability' in general is not something easily defined. Finally, their measure of testability is defined in terms of the number of injected dependencies!
- [Effects of Dependency Injection on Maintainability](http://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/csse_fac/34/). They compare projects using DI to projects not using DI they found on SourceForge and see if there are any differences in cohesion metrics. To reduce bias, they paired off the projects to be as similar as possible. Ultimately, they saw signals that projects with a lot of DI were somewhat less coupled than projects with only a little DI. However, it seems there was no significant difference in cohesion between the DI projects and their non-DI pair, so it could be a consequence of the specific domains. They list "no correlation" as their primary result and the "maybe it helps a little?" as a topic for further study.
- [Empirically assessing the impact of dependency injection on the development of web service applications](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2011308). The abstract doesn't really explain what they're looking for. I dug up and read a preprint and as far as I can tell it's actually about how well automated tooling can discover services. Services written in a DI style were more easily discovered. Also, it cites the previous study I listed as providing empirical evidence that DI reduces coupling, which is the opposite of what that paper claimed.

For these three papers (and for [An Empirical Study into Use of Dependency Injection in Java](https://academic.microsoft.com/#/detail/2154122606?FORM=DACADP), which is only about detection) I followed up on all the papers that cited them, none of which were about determining the effectiveness of DI. Given all of this, I'm confident saying that **no**, we do not yet have empirical evidence on whether or not DI improves software quality.

Comment: This answers the question directly. +1

Comment: @MatthewJamesBriggs I'm not the downvoter, but, does answering the question directly matter if the answer is misleading or incomplete???

Comment: @svidgen I don't see how the answer is incomplete. The question was "do we have empirical evidence that DI works?" and the answer is "no." That's says nothing about whether or not it does work, just that there is no research on it.

Comment: Incomplete and misleading in that you're answer limits the scope of "evidence" to "papers that you've (sic) been able to find" and blanketed over "effectiveness" without respect for the actual purposes of DI, and that you have therefore **concluded** that the answer is "no" without qualification... I would argue that, if you're going to "directly" answer the question, as @MatthewJamesBriggs suggests you did, there's a heavy onus on you to dig deep and be able to demonstrate with high certainty that you've explored all the avenues ...

Comment: And I guess, when combine that with your hasty assessment of the one resource you *did* cite, I might even call this answer *very* misleading. Because, aside from all the potential evidence you're ignoring, you're taking documented evidence and immediately discounting it for reasons not fully explained. ... If I were to claim, for example, that "there's no evidence we landed on the moon" because the "only" paper I've ever read on the matter was from a "deprecated" textbook revision that I don't trust, I hope you'd be skeptical of my methods ...

Comment: @svidgen no need to be rude about it. I expanded my answer and added a few more studies I was able to dig up.

Comment: No intention of being rude...